# Should unit testing test dependency interaction?

Tags: java, unit-testing

Let's say I have the following interfaces and implementations:

**RequestHandler.java**

```
public interface RequestHandler {

    public Response handle(Request request);

}
```

**RequestHandlerImpl.java**

```
public class RequestHandlerImpl implements RequestHandler {

    private HttpHandler httpHandler;
    private SQLHandler sqlHandler;

    public RequestHandlerImpl(HttpHandler httpHandler, SQLHandler sqlHandler) {
        this.httpHandler = httpHandler;
        this.sqlHandler = sqlHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public Response handle(Request request) {
        // Disassemble request and dispatch to HttpHandler and SQLHandler
        // Return response based off interaction with handlers
    }

}
```

For this specific implementation of `RequestHandler` I'm delegating some of the request processing to a `HttpHandler` and a `SQLHandler`. When unit testing, should I mock out the `HttpHandler` and `SQLHandler` and actually test that my request is being delegated to these objects? Or do I only need to test my implementation from a contract-based standpoint, i.e. test that my `handle(Request request)` method returns a meaningful response?

Comment: Ref. [Integration Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing): "Integration testing is the phase in software testing in which individual software modules are combined and tested as a group. It occurs after unit testing and before validation testing."

Comment: @user2864740 Except that this isn't integration testing, I'm mocking out the dependencies

Comment: Unit tests are best isolated to one class at a time, in this case `RequestHandlerImpl`.  You should inject mock instances of `httpHandler` and `sqlHandler` so that `RequestHandlerImpl` is fully exercised by its associated unit test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should.

It might be possible that your unit test of `RequestHandlerImpl` fails, although the class itself works perfectly fine. It just got betrayed by a bug in the implementation of `HttpHandler` or `SQLHandler`, which should only appear when running the tests for these classes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should mock out the `HttpHandler` and  `SQLHandler` objects for your unit test. The unit test should verify that the code in `RequestHandlerImpl` does what you expect, which includes correctly using the injected dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Purpose of unit testing is to verify whether your RequestHandlerImpl.handle method does the routing correctly.

If you unit test the RequestHandlerImpl definitely you should mock SqlHandler and HttpHandler and test that request is being delegated to those mocks correctly.

Why those should be mocked? Why not injecting real HttpHandler and SqlHandler object?

Because your unit test suppose to test only the RequestHandlerImpl. If your RequestHandlerImpl unit test fails due to HttpHandlers problem, it will be a wrong indication.

So first think what is the unit you are going to test. identify the other dependent units for your functionality. Then mock all other units work.